# Does the 'it' variable in GHCi Haskell mutate?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ghci

Just started with Haskell and it is said that Haskell has immutable variables. Then why does 'it' variable keep mutating its value every time an expression is entered in GHCi prompt?

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> 7*2
14
Prelude> it
14
Prelude> "foo"
"foo"
Prelude> it
"foo"
Prelude>
```

Comment: It's not mutation; it's just shadowing.

Comment: Please read https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#idp46760125930848

Answer (score 8):

Expressions typed into ghci have an implicit type of

```
it :: (Show a) => IO a
```

In other words everything you do is in the IO monad (the "Show" means you have to be able to convert the result to text for printing). When you type a series of expressions in, it works like this:

```
do
   it <- foo
   it <- bar
```

Haskell's "do" notation desugars into nested lambdas something like this

```
  foo >>= $ \it ->
     bar >>= $ \it -> ... -- and so on.
```

In other words the value of "it" is not changing, rather a new value is being declared in a scope that shadows the previous one.

Comment: The last part is true. The first part isn't quite, and is confusing.

Comment: @dfeuer: Please feel free to elaborate.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Well, there are actually 3 different ways ghci handles expressions.  The one you described, showable expressions without IO, and IO expressions without a showable result.